# How do I sudo if in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I need to check for a directory in the home directory of another user. Normally I would sudo but that forks another process and I also lose my environment.

For example, I have:

```
if [[ -d "/home/otheruser/svn" ]];
then
   echo "SVN exists"
else
   echo "SVN does not exist"
fi
```

I need the the test condition to run with root permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to run it under a subshell. Example:

```
if sudo bash -c '[[ -d "/home/otheruser/svn" ]]'
then
  echo "SVN exists"
else
  echo "SVN does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 46):

```
if sudo test -d "/home/otheruser/svn"; then
```

Comment: Better answer by far, because there's no risk of double evaluation: If someone tried to parameterize the other answer but did it badly (ie. `sudo bash -c "[[ -d $filename ]]"`) you could have malicious filenames executed as commands (consider `filename='foo ]] || rm -rf $HOME || [[ true'`). By contrast, this answer is completely safe: `if sudo test -d "$filename"` won't run any command other than `test`.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly better for the specific case of doing a test supported by `/bin/test`. I was giving a general solution for a "sudo if". If someone is doing a test supported by the bash builtin `[[` but not by `/bin/test`-- or, say, using a pipeline as the test condition-- they're going to have a bad time.